# IOS Navigation Non Heiarchical

Tags: ios, navigation, segue

I have an iOS app using iOS 5 and Xcode 4.3.2 that is made up of 7 view controllers.  VC1 links to VC2, VC2 can link to VC3-VC7 and each of those controllers can link to each other (think of it as a side bar navigation).  If I use segues the views are repeatedly added to the stack and if a user goes back and forth it can use a large amount of memory.  How can I implement this navigation where I release the previous controller?  They are all small controllers so loading them takes little time/processor/memory.  Can I presentViewController and then release the presentingViewController somehow?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a UINavigationController, you can use the push and pop view controller methods to go back and forth.  [popToViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController%3aanimated%3a) is described here, along with 3 other helpful methods.

Comment: If I use a navigation controller to push and pop the views won't there be a "redirect" feel in the program flow.  For example entering from VC2 I push VC4 onto stack.  User now wants to go to VC6 so I pop VC4 (not animated) and push VC6 (animated).  Won't there still be a "flash" of VC2 when I pop VC4 before VC6 is pushed and displayed?  Can I get the cross dissolve effect with a navigation controller?

Comment: In that case, you could push the view first, then update by directly editing the `viewControllers` property of the navigation controller (removeObjectAtIndex)

Comment: Implemented this solution to manage the stack avoiding duplicates.  Keeps the application real memory usage under control.  Thanks.  I would up vote but don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well seems like there should be no problem from VC1 to VC2. For the VC3 - VC7 you could:

- Present as modalViewController instead of pushing that to the stack.

Or:
- Use the popToViewController:animated: function of your UINavigationController if the Controller is already present in the stack of controllers, otherwise push it. Like

```
// Assuming u need to push VC6
for(UIViewController *controller in [urNavController viewControllers]){
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[VC6 class]])
        {
           [urNavController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            VC6 *VC6controller = [[VC6 alloc] init];
           [urNavController pushViewController:VC6controller];
        }

}
```

Comment: I originally had the views presented as modals but my understanding is they are pushed onto the stack and then the parent (or now presenting) view controller dismisses that view when you want to return.  In my case entering from VC2 the user could go to VC4 and from there go to VC6 without returning to VC2.  Will this not build up the stack?  Your navigation controller option looks interesting.  Is there a quick way to add a navigation controller to my app without rebuilding it all, from app delegate maybe?  Im using storyboards and ARC BTW.

Comment: Well dunno if I completely get your "Is there a quick way to add a navigation controller to my app without rebuilding it all" but what I'd do is to create a subclass of the UINavigationController first like myNavController. In myNavController simply override the pushViewController:animated: function and add the code written above in it. After this the only thing u've got to do is to make the current navController u're using in your app as myNavController, and u can easily test if the code works, without changing anything else on your app. ;P hope this help.

Comment: My current application didn't use a navigation controller.  I was able to quickly add one via storyboards by selecting Editor-> Embed In -> Navigation Controller from my root view.  Thats more for others that may not have known.  I accepted the other answer since it gave me the ability to really control the stack, this solution would allow all VCs to be loaded once (which is much better than what my original implementation was).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UINavigationController`'s `- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated` method to remove any view controllers below the topmost one.  Since the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array is an immutable one, you could not use any `NSMutableArray`'s `removeObject...` methods directly on the `viewControllers` array.  You would have to make a `mutableCopy` into a mutable array, remove any (hidden) view controllers you wish to discard from the mutable array, and pass the resulting slimmed-down stack of view controllers to the above method.  Since your topmost view controller would be unchanged, there would be no transition animation in your case (see discussion below), so you could also set the viewControllers property directly without bothering with the `animated:` argument.

From Apple's documentation:

Discussion
You can use this method to update or replace the current view controller stack without pushing or popping each controller explicitly. In addition, this method lets you update the set of controllers without animating the changes, which might be appropriate at launch time when you want to return the navigation controller to a previous state.

If animations are enabled, this method decides which type of transition to perform based on whether the last item in the items array is already in the navigation stack. If the view controller is currently in the stack, but is not the topmost item, this method uses a pop transition; if it is the topmost item, no transition is performed. If the view controller is not on the stack, this method uses a push transition. Only one transition is performed, but when that transition finishes, the entire contents of the stack are replaced with the new view controllers. For example, if controllers A, B, and C are on the stack and you set controllers D, A, and B, this method uses a pop transition and the resulting stack contains the controllers D, A, and B.